# JQuery-UI Widget undefined when using interval

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to create a Jquery UI widget that starts an interval on creation. The function called on each interval timeout is supposed to be overrideable and therefore placed in the `options` object.

I can start the interval from outside the widget, and I can call the overrideable function from outside the widget. But when the interval tries to call the overrideable function, it's `undefined`.

Here is my widget:

```
jQuery.widget("awesome.me", {
    options: {
        verbose:false,                        // just some setting
        onTimeOut: function(){                // this is the function that is called by the timeout and that should be overrideable 
            console.log("on timeOut called");
        }
    },
    _create: function(){
        console.log(this.options);            // logging the options object
    }, 
    _members: {                               // a private object to hold internal settings and stuff, for example the interval instance
        interval: null
    },
    start: function(){        
        this._members.interval = setInterval(this.doIt, 2000);
    },
    stop: function(){
        clearInterval(this._members.interval);
    },
    doIt: function(){
        console.log(this.options);            // here I would like to call my onTimeOut function, but the options are undefined, because THIS is undefined
    }
});
```

From the outside, in the script I do this to instantiate my widget and start the interval:

```
$(document).me();                              // I am not overriding the function for now
var widget = $(document).data("awesome-me");   // to facilitate access to my widget I grab the instance and put it in a normal variable
widget.start();                                // start() will set the interval
```

If I where to call `widget.doIt()`, the console would show something like this:

```
 Object {classes: Object, disabled: false, create: null, verbose: false}
```

But when I run the script, every two seconds this appears:

```
undefined
```

So from my understanding, when I call `widget.start()`, the interval will start calling `this.doIt` every 2 seconds, but inside the `doIt` function, when it tries to log the `options` object, it is gone. So my `widget` variable still has the correct instance of my widget and I can call every function I want. But when the interval times out, it holds some other widget instance where the function `doIt` exists, but `this` is undefined.

What I don't understand is: why? How I can fix this?

Comment: It could be helpful to make a full [mcve].

Comment: @TheSharpieOne, No it doesn't seem so. I am only loading one `jquery-3.1.0.min.js` and a custom `jquery-ui.js`

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara my example is complete, it runs, is verifiable and quite minimal (as minimal as I can make it so it still runs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `this._members.interval = setInterval(this.doIt, 2000);`

When `this.doIt` is called, it is called with `this` being `window`, which in turn is really, `window.options` which is being accessed in `doIt` (do `console.log(this)` to see what it is inside of `doIt` when it is ran).

The fix is to bind or execute `doIt` passing `this`.

```
this._members.interval = setInterval(this.doIt.bind(this), 2000);
```

or

```
var self = this;
this._members.interval = setInterval(function(){self.doIt();}, 2000);
```

Comment: interesting, I tried the `bind` variant and it works as expected! I think I have to read more about JS once this project is over. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just a note on compatibility, `bind` does not work in IE8. I assume most people are no longer supporting it and left it out of the answer.

Comment: You would be surprised.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I am still deciding if supporting IE8 is worth it. Too many other neat little things get complicated when writing them for IE8.